# What's the best place to trigger an event in MVC?

Tags: oop, model-view-controller

Having an MVC system, is it better to trigger events in the controller or in the services that are injected in has dependencies?

Eg.

```
class MyController
{
    $brainStorage->store($yellowBrain);

    $EventDispatcher->dispatch(new BrainCreatedEvent($yellowBrain));

...
```

Or should be the storage service to trigger the event?

I prefer that control classes are the only ones aware of the domain events.

What are pros and cons?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the case your controller starts doing event handling it will fail single responsability, so the best option in my opinion is to create an abstraction and let the client decide the algorith to inject in application service that will orchestrate your workflow (Use of strategy pattern, IOC, remove code smells, your code will start to be extensible and SOLID)
 Hope this helps decide, Kind regards!

Comment: Elias wich is the responsability of a controller? Single one? :-)

Comment: I asked where to trigger not where to listen. Trigger is not the same as listen. Triggering is management unaware.

Comment: The app service should trigger the events so it is responsible from reading the business object->modify it->persist changes-> trigger events after saving. If you place all that logic in this class, you can have multiple clients consuming a single service.